# mongodb: java: How to update a field in MongoDB using expression with existing value

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-update

I need to update a field using some expression. Given a `DBObject query`, how can I multiply or divide given field by an argument `value`?

How can I write a function performing operation something like this, but in Java:

```
function(DBObject queryObject, String fieldToUpdate, Double argumentValue) { 
    collection.find(queryObject).forEach(function(e) {
        // update field given by input argument "fieldToUpdate", something like..
        // e.put(fieldToUpdate, e.get(fieldToUpdate)/argumentValue); ??
        collection.save(e);
    });
}
```

Is it possible using `"$set"` and `find()` or `findAndModify()`? If yes, how can update existing value using an expression like `existingValue / argumentValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, MongoDB doesn't allow you to update the value of a field according to an existing value of a field. Which means, you can't do the following SQL:

```
UPDATE foo SET field1 = field1 / 2;
```

In MongoDB, you will need to do this in your application, but be aware that this is no longer an atomic operation as you need to read and then write.